# Delete multiple columns by reference using reverse selection in data.Table

Tags: r, data.table

I want to delete the columns that are not in a list using reference.

```
library("data.table")
df <- data.frame("ID"=1:10,"A"=1:10,"B"=1:10,"C"=1:10,"D"=1:10)
setDT(df,key="ID")
list_to_keep <- c("ID","A","B","C")
df[,!names(df)%in%list_to_keep,with=FALSE]
```

gives me a selection of the columns that I want to delete, but when I do:

```
df <- data.frame("ID"=1:10,"A"=1:10,"B"=1:10,"C"=1:10,"D"=1:10)
setDT(df,key="ID")
list_to_keep <- c("ID","A","B","C")
df[,!names(df)%in%list_to_keep:=NULL,with=FALSE]
```

I get `LHS of := isn't a column names ('character' or positions ('integer' or 'numeric')`. What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Not sure about `data.table`, but in base R you'd need to use `which(!names(df)%in%list_to_keep)`. Right now you only get a boolean vector, you need a vector of positions.

Comment: @Kenji, Why `:=NULL` in line `df[,!names(df)%in%list_to_keep:=NULL,with=FALSE] ?
`

Comment: @ParthChaudhary I don't want to make a copy of the data table, hence `:=NULL` to delete by reference instead of assignment

Comment: @Kenji, okay got it , delete by reference due to `DT` usage

Comment: I can't see how it is possibly a duplicate of the other question. Whilst part of the answer in the other question could possibly solve my problem, the question itself is different in the following aspects: 1) It doesn't ask specifically for deleting columns through reference. 2) It doesn't ask specifically for reverse selection. The main answer for the other question is something like `df <- df[list_to_keep]`, which doesn't answer my problem at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the `setdiff` to get the `names` of the dataset that are not in the `list_to_keep` and assign (`:=`) it to `NULL`

```
df[, setdiff(names(df), list_to_keep) := NULL]
```

As @rosscova mentioned, using `which` on the logical `vector` can be used to get the position of the column and to assign the columns to `NULL`

```
df[, which(!names(df)%in%list_to_keep):=NULL]
```

Comment: Can also pass an integer vector, so `df[,which(!names(df)%in%list_to_keep):=NULL]` works too.

Answer (score 1):

`LHS` of `:=` is "A character vector of column names (or numeric positions) or a variable that evaluates as such."

`!names(df)%in%list_to_keep` is logical vector.

So,

```
df[,names(df)[!names(df)%in%list_to_keep]:=NULL]
```

will work.